# Is the phrase "there's no turning back for sure" correct?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I would like to ask if the following phrase is correct:

> There's no turning back for sure

The meaning of the sentence should be that there's no way to turn back and the *for sure* at the end should emphasize that who wrote the sentence is sure that that there's no way to turn back.

Is it correct to write such a phrase?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, but personally I'd prefer a comma after *back*. Also, on EL&U, please use `*italics*` or `"quote characters"` for inline quotations, and `> blockquotes` for quotations set apart from the body of your post. I'll fix that for you this time.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response and advices. If you write an answer I can accept it so you get reputation points :)

Comment: Possibly *irrevocable moment*, or *point of no return*?

Comment: @tonix Sadly, the standards here are such that when I answer, not only do I have to be right, but I have to prove I'm right :) That work I'll leave for someone else. I stopped caring about rep years ago, when I found out you can't eat it :). But if you like rep, feel free to add your own answer, based on my comment or not, and I will vote you up.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes, it should mean something like that.

Comment: Putting "for sure" at the end, especially without a comma, can be ambiguous in terms of what the "no" applies to.  "no [turning back for sure]" could mean there is always equivocation in turning back.  "For sure, there is no turning back" might be better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "correct"....  *There's definitely no turning back* would be more formal.

> **[for sure](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for+sure)** *Idioms: Informal*. Certainly; unquestionably: *We'll win for sure*.  (American Heritage)